# Excel interprets all date formats as US

Tags: excel, date, format, regional-settings

A colleague extracts data from a web source using Chrome. He saves the data in xlsx format and sends to me. His computer is in US date format (M/d/yyyy).

My computer is in UK date format (dd/MM/yyyy). When my excel opens the file, it interprets the first two digits (dd) as month. If dd<13, excel formats these incorrectly as mm/dd/yyyy. If dd>12, excel formats the cell as "General".

Two examples how the dates look like in the file:
this is July:
31/07/2021 -> my excel formats the cell as General
this is August:
12/08/2021 -> excel formats as Date, December 8, 2021

Sounds like a simple thing to fix...so far, I've tried the following:

1. Changed my computer's date delimiter to "."; no impact, 8.12.21 is treated as December
2. Changed my computer's date setting to US MM/dd/yyyy. No impact, 12/08/2021 is still treated as December and July date as 'General'
   Also none of these had any impact:
3. Changed my computer's date setting to US M/dd/yyyy (the same as the colleague's)
4. Opened excel in safe mode
5. Extracted the data directly from the web source as csv.
6. Changed Chrome default language from English US to English UK, then extracted the data as csv, changed computer setting to US data, then opened in excel
7. Changed settings in computer back to mm/dd/yyyy, created a text file myself, imported to excel -> here dates are correct
8. After all these, changed the column format to Short Date.

edit: also tried
9. Get Data from text/csv instead of file open

In summary, whenever this file has a cell 'dd/mm/yyyy', excel converts it to mm/dd/yyyy and Date format. If it cannot, the cell is in General format.

As a result, the filters do not work because some the dates are either incorrect or not dates at all.

I could of course write a macro that reformats cells which are in Date format and converts strings in General format to dates. Although I can do this, it seems like a heavy solution for a simple(?) issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the format in excel ,Click 'Home' Tab in the Ribbon-> In 'number 'Group->Choose 'more number format'-> 'custom'->change the 'type' as "DD-MM-YYYY".

If you find it difficult, select the column and To change the date display in Excel follow these steps:

Right click on the column

Go to Format Cells > Custom

Enter dd/mm/yyyy in the available space.

The dates listed in your spreadsheet should be converted to the new format.

Comment: I tried this both ways and also using the format brush. Both for the entire column and single cell. Neither solves the issue. E.g. 08/12/2021, after dd.mm.yyyy is applied, becomes 08.12.2021 but month is still December, not August. It seems that at this point, Excel relies on its initial treatment and formatting does not change that.